# don't want to remove CDATA using strip_tags()

Tags: php, html

Some of my customer wants to add google re-marketing code to their website and there is a panel to make it so.

I'm using `strip_tags` to remove unnecessary tags from the code (security reason) but the function also removed the `CDATA`.

How can I exclude it?

Sample Remarketing Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   /* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 123456789;
var google_conversion_label = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;

var google_remarketing_only = true;

/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/123456789/?label=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&guid=ON&script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

PHP Code :

```
$userContent = addslashes(strip_tags($data["analytics_code"],'<script><noscript><img><div>'));
```

Output is like that :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   /*  */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/123456789/?label=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&guid=ON&script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) is rather simple in it's functionality. Also, as a general rule, regular expressions are not able to parse HTML due to the fact that HTML, XML, etc do not fit into the class of regular languages. In other words you are left to use an HTML/XML parser to fish out the information you need.

Comment: Since you are new to the community: if an answer satisfies you, please use the "accept" function to accept that answer, awarding the person who wrote it the reputation increase for it. If you later on find a better answer, you can always change the accept flag to that one.